# How to connect to a ws port whe nthe node is in a docker container

Tags: rpc, docker

I have a Substrate node that I build locally and also into a docker container in CI.

When I use my local build or when I use `docker run --network host`, I can connect to the websocket endpoint on port 9944 just fine.

However, when I use `docker run -p 9944:9944`, I am not able to connect to the websocket endpoint.

This sounds very similar to what is described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54101508/how-do-you-dockerize-a-websocket-server

So my question is whether the node's websocket address is listening on 0.0.0.0 or something else, and how can I tell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try adding `--rpc-external` to be able to use `0.0.0.0`.